# Django - I cant migrate my database because of my forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms, migrate

I am trying to migrate my django project but there is this error:

```sh
(venv) F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu>python src\manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: blog_category

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "src\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 65, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\src\try_django\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from blog.views import blog_post_create_view
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\src\blog\views.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .forms import BlogPostForm
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\src\blog\forms.py", line 16, in <module>
    class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\src\blog\forms.py", line 17, in BlogPostForm
    class Meta:
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\src\blog\forms.py", line 24, in Meta
    'category': forms.Select(choices=category_list(), attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\src\blog\utils.py", line 6, in category_list
    if not Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name').exists():
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 766, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 522, in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1110, in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1140, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "F:\repos\meetmetrics.eu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: blog_category
```

This is my **forms.py**:

```py
from django import forms

from .models import BlogPost
from .utils import category_list

class BlogPostForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'category', 'content', 'image', 'private', 'tags']

        widgets ={
        
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(choices=category_list(), attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control-file'}),
            'private': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-label'}),
            'tags': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

This is my **utils.py**:

```py
from .models import Category

def category_list():
    choice_list = []

    if not Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name').exists():
        choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name')
        for item in choices:
            choice_list.append(item)
    else:
        choice_list.append('') 
    
    return choice_list
```

If I remove from **forms.py** this line and try to migrate everthing works:

```py
'category': forms.Select(choices=category_list(), attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
```

Do you have any solution or any idea why is that? If you need more info ask me, I am not sure I gave you all you need to help me.

Comment: Have you just added the `Category` model?

Comment: Because if so, that's the reason :) You will need to migrate the DB changes before you can start using them!

Comment: @urbanespaceman can you be more specific about  "Have you just added the `Category` model? "

Comment: Er ... Not sure how to be more specific about that question. Have you just added the model? Is that what the migration is doing?

Comment: Nop, I use migrate for all my models

Comment: OK, you've misunderstood the question, and I honestly don't know how to phrase it more simply. Have you literally just added the Category model, and this is what the current migration is trying to do? Pretty sure this is the case and that's why you're getting this error ...

Comment: Where to add the model, I am so sorry i dont get it :))

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I've run out of ways to ask this question. I get the feeling your core problem is that you need to work through a thorough Django tutorial. Might I recommend the Django Girls one - it's really very good.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @urbanespaceman for exapmple let's say i just added the Category model. Is there any other way to import my category in forms.py without error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first delete the **pycache** dir, then delete the everything in the migrations folder BUT, DONT delete **init**.py in migrations. After that I would try to migrate.